# What is wrong with my script?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, csv

I am trying to insert values to a csv file through the following script....the script works fine but in the output, the values are not properly arranged in order..

```
<?php
require_once '../config.php';
$month = $_GET['month'];
$sq="select * from  employee where month ='$month'";
$sql=mysql_query($sq);

$row = array();
$row[] = 'Employee Code';
$row[] = 'Employee Name';
$row[] = 'DOJ';
$data .= join(',', $row)."\n"; // Join all values without any trailing commas 
$row = array(); // We must clear the previous values
while($rs = mysql_fetch_object($sql))
{
$row[] = $rs->employee_code;
$row[] = $rs->employee_name;
$row[] = $rs->emp_dateofjoin;
$row[] = "\n";
}
$data .= join(',', $row);

// Output the headers to download the file
header("Content-type: application/x-msdownload");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=test.csv");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");
echo $data;
?>
```

The values are added in the csv file with one blank cell in the beginning of a row. except the first row.

Comment: Your script is currently vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. You should escape the `$_GET['month']` with http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php or similar.

Comment: You could add a few lines of the actual csv ouput (say 3-5 lines) and the the expected output. That way it's clearer to see what's going wrong and then dig into the code and say why it is going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without even looking at it, what's wrong with the core of your script is that you are using `mysql_*` functions. So don't. You should instead move to [PDO](http://il2.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) (awesome), or [mysqli](http://il2.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) (good).

other then that, have you considered adding an `ORDER BY` clause to your query?

Comment: sunil might appreciate if you elaborated "So don't" with some suggestion how they should replace the `mysql_` functions.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could also look into ORDER BY FIELD() DESC, might also help arrange whatever you want in descending. just a thought.

```
SELECT * FROM employee WHERE month = '$month' AND order by field(field1,field2,field3,field4) desc
```

Or you could use a while loop inside of a foreach with regular expression and ereg() to scan through the characters and then set what and when you want something displayed. Another method is to sort the information from the highest populated elements to lower.

Comment: actually my problem is sorting out the fetched data in test.csv file. The datas are fetching fine but the problem is their arrangement in the csv file

Comment: Oh okay look at <http://www.phpclasses.org/package/6329-PHP-Read-and-sort-CSV-file-data-into-array.html> its a PHPClass that you can use to "Read and sort CSV file data into array", and then you could update the CSV File once you have everything arranged as you want.